# ssh from my ec2 instance to my ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh, airflow

because i am running an application (airflow) in a python virtual environment on my ec-2 instance and i want to run a command in my default python environment on the same ec2-instance, i thought it was easier to ssh to my own instance and execute the command.

the problem i have is that i cannot connect to my own instance.

i added my security group id of my ec2-instance to my inbound configuration (ssh on port 22) but this did not work. 
it does work when i set my ssh inbound configuration on port 22 from anywhere, but i don't want to do that.

my outbound config allows all traffic.

Comment: Maybe you're adding the wrong IP for inbound. Sometimes, your local IP may be different from the incoming IP that AWSinstances will see if you go through an internet proxy.

Comment: AWS' console allows you to pick "My IP" when editing inbound rules. [See here](https://i.imgur.com/JHvtJij.png)

Comment: @RaGe no, the "My IP" refers to the machine your are using to acces the aws UI

Comment: Am I understanding this correctly - you have an EC2 instance and you simply want to ssh to the same ec2 instance (localhost) to run a python script? Why can't you use the PythonOperator to do this? I believe you can pass the python environment in as an argument.

Comment: also, how about using 127.0.0.1 as your ssh destination so you're routing through local loop?

Comment: @SimonD yes that is also an alternative i was thinking about. I posed this question because ssh to your own instance might be useful

Comment: @VincentClaes - I am struggling to think of a situation where it would be useful to ssh to your own instance when it could be completed without ssh?

Answer (score 1):

If you are connecting from another EC2 instance in the same subnet, you'll want to allow the private IP of that EC2 instance, not your local address.

Comment: i tried to add my private ip address to the inbound ssh configuration but that did not work.